# How to prevent reset-timeout in ZingChart

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

I'm making a dynamic graphic that shows me a variable curve.
I don't want to have the data reloaded. I want then continuously move in the screen.
Of course I can put a very long "reset-timeout" attribute, but sometime it will be reloaded, and I don't want this.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Full disclosure, I'm a member of the ZingChart team.

Like you mentioned, just set a really high timeout. What is the graphs purpose and why can't it reset? How reasonable is it for this client side graph to run forever?

You can simply query the chart and save the current data before it resets using our API method [getdata](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/developers/api-methods/#zingchart__exec__api__getseriesvalues).